# Corrupted hard drive - how can I rescue my files?

Tags: 12.04, boot, freeze

Lets get things straight: I'm a bit of a noob.

My Ubuntu System was not working well, so I went on the live CD and checked the system, everything went smoothly. So rebooted it without the Live CD and once again it would not work. So i repeated said process, but the system check was taking a long time, so i cancelled it midway through, despite the warning that it could corrupt the drive (I know, I'm stupid). So now it gets to the Ubuntu purple screen, with 5 dots that normally light on and off as it loads, and it just freezes there.

What can I do to retrieve the system with my data? I have got everything backed up by Ubuntu One, and saved to a USB now it is being discontinued, but have one VERY important document that for some reason Ubuntu One wasnt synced to save.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Boot with the live CD, then access the partition via the file viewer (called nautilus).

Click on XXXGB Volume:

[image]

Then navigate to `home - <username>` then your document, and copy it across to a USB.

Then reinstall from the live CD.